# How to make a div accessable only for authenticated users

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, roles

I have a  inside page.aspx, and I have created a role called Premium. I want all users to be able to see page.aspx, but only Premium users can see the div.

My web.condig

```
<location path="?">
<system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Premium" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

I don't now how to write it so only users in the role Premium can see the

Comment: When you say div, you mean a part of your page warped with `div` - correct ?

Comment: You should read some basics about authentication, authorization, validation (in WebServer/Controllers/Code-Behind) and security filtering(in aspx-files etc.), and why you should use all at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to use an `if` statement to control output of that part of the page:

```
<% if(User.IsInRole("Premium")) { %>
<div> blah </div>
<% } %>
```

You could, of course, make a `UserControl` or similar that contains this logic instead, thus pushing the conditional expression out of the host page and having the page simply render the control always.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the premium section a partial view which has it's own method in the controller,  for which you could require the role *Premium*.

Comment: The term 'partial view' is an MVC thing, really - and the question appears (based on what little information is available!) to be a webforms question.

Answer (score 0):

in your page.aspx, do the following:

```
<%if (Request.IsAuthenticated){ %>
    <%if HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("premium"){ %>
        <div>premium content</div>
    <%} %>
<%}%>
```